# How to know if a photo is good -people judge

Tags: human-vision-system

I am new here,I came  here because I have a personal issue but I think it's more than my issue because even photographers or a models wants to know the others people opinion about their photo.How do you know with not asking around about the opinion of others if a human photo is good? (My personal problem is,I havent confidence on this issue is took some photos I say o I look nice I post not good , I ask around not good.Ok, it's not all of photos that are not good but there are some.I don't want to ask around I want to know alone but I think and the professionals(photographer, models etc) would like too do if there is a way to use it)

Comment: it's difficult to understand your question. Are you specifically referring to self-portraits?

Comment: Yes , humans.Example,you get a photo of yourself but you don't know ,if is nice picture or not.For you maybe it is,but 100 persons it isn't. I hope you get it now what I mean

Comment: experience: the more photos you shoot, the more feedback you will get, making it easier for you to judge whether a photo is good or not. also, I wouldn't care too much for the opinion of others - develop your own style. if you're into high key photography, then don't be afraid if laymen are saying "boy, that's a bit bright..." - the most important thing (if you are not a professional) avout your photos is that **you** like them.

Comment: Before I write an answer.. this is REALLY hard to work out what you're saying. Is it along the lines of 'what qualities should a photo (of a person) have in order to be classed as good)'?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What makes a photo a good photo?](https://photo.stackexchange.com/questions/2296/what-makes-a-photo-a-good-photo)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If I was providing feedback on an image, in my opinion these are some qualities to look for to judge if it's good or not, be it in my own work or someone elses.

1. Is it in focus.
2. More importantly are the eyes in focus.
3. Is there any blur, e.g. motion or camera shake.
4. Is the framing correct (have you cut off limbs in awkward places).
5. Is the white balance right (personal pet peev)
6. Is it correctly exposed (no blown highlights)
7. Are there distractions (e.g. people behind)
8. Clear seperation of background and subject (can be achieved with depth of field or lighting).

All of the above can be achieved ON camera very easily without editing. The next list is a bit more advanced..

9. Well lit, so non flat lighting. The more the creative the better.

The next list are what I'd expect from a properly edited image, however these can be require more , and in some circles can be considered wrong.

10. No skin blemishes, caused by lighting, makeup etc
11. No stray hairs.
12. (if you remove things like moles, freckles etc, use the liquify tool to boof hair or change the subjects shape make sure you check with the subject first)
13. If a composite does it look real or overtly fake.

Finally, some things to be mindful of.

13. Be inspired. But don't rip anyone elses work off.
14. Try avoid photo clichés and faux-pas.. selected colour is the perfect example.
15. Instagram isn't real life.

Like everything, the more you shoot, the more you learn, the more you can find you can flex these rules.

I'd suggest joining an online forum or community that provides critique of images, you may not like what they say to begin with but they can point you in the right direction on improving your work. You will always be the harshest critic, and friends/family will always go 'OMG that photo is amazing' which always boosts an ego, but always take it at face value, chances are they don't want to hurt your feelings or may not necessarily be able to provided the in depth feedback you're really after.

IMHO if you don't hate the majority of your own work, you're doing something wrong.

Comment: The problem with your list is that it's entirely subjective. This makes a good photo portrait for you, but in many situations ALL your points can be broken on purpose to achieve certain effect the author is going for. Would that make it a worse photo? Of course not.

Comment: @walther the OP explicitly mentions models.

Comment: @walther apologies, missed the 'good photo portrait for you'. It's the reason I included a caveat of 'Like everything, the more you shoot, the more you learn, the more you can find you can flex these rules.' BUT on someone asking for advice starting out those are the things I would always look out for, break the 'bad habits' before you learn you can reintroduce them.

Answer (score 0):

I have a little trick. It's a sort of self-training.

1. Take a lot of pictures. Dozens! Hundreds! All with slightly differing lighting, point of view, focus... whatever. Don't care about quality.
2. Look at two or three of those images. It doesn't matter which ones you select.
3. Then, choose the best-looking image of these two or three.
4. Think really, really hard: Why is it the best image?

I did it with three random pictures from Wikimedia Commons:
[image]

[image]

[image]

Which one is the best image?

In my opinion, the second one is the best. The bright and dark parts are well balanced. You can really see the depth of the image. You realize instantly what this picture is about: A sculpture of a meager human body fixed to a wall.

The first one (cannon at Fort Sumter) does not give information that quickly. You don't see how deep that cavern is. That metal thing is not instantly recognized as a cannon.

In the third picture, you don't recognize what these people are doing (Dance? Fitness? Aerobic?), and the people in the background are irritating.

This technique helps you think about images. It helps you identify objective (blur, focus) and subjective (theme) criteria.